# Проблемы с запуском автотестов на Bamboo

Tags: python, windows, selenium

Дан набор тестов (Selenium Webdriver + Python), запускаю их на Bamboo сервере. Тесты падают, потому что физически Bamboo не запускает браузер и во всех тестах Selenium не может найти нужный элемент на странице (при том почему-то каждый раз разный).

Запускал тесты разными способами, и просто набором консольных команд, и bat файлом, который хранится на сервере.

Если запускать прямо руками на сервере, то все нормально, браузер запускается, тесты проходят. Браузер - Firefox. Версии python, selenium везде одни и те же.

Как это исправить?

Comment: На какой ОС стоит Bamboo? Какую ошибку показывают тесты? Подключаешься к серверу через ssh или к удаленному рабочему столу?

Comment: @Danil Там просто Windows7 Тесты показывают ошибку, что элемент не видим и с ним нельзя взаимодействовать(например, заполняю поле логина)